# How to store output of a awk script command into a variable?

Tags: bash, awk, scripting

I have an awk script, `testscript.script`, with command:

`$5 > 0 {print $1}`

which outputs

```
 Lebron
 Kobe
 James
 Tony
```

How can I store this command into a variable `var` such that when I say `print var` at any point in the code, the above output will print?

Answer (score 1):

You need command substitution, `$()`:

```
var=$(awk ...)
```

The STDOUT of the `awk` command will be saved in variable `var`.

Now, you can do:

```
echo "$var"
```

to get the output.

Comment: extending this command substitution method to the command `var = $($3 + $4 + $5 > 500 {print $1 $2 | "sort"})` produces syntax errors. What went wrong here? Normally, stdout for this command will display.

Comment: @KevinMoy There must be no spaces around `=`, you need: `var=$(your_command_here)`

Comment: very strange... I seem to get syntax errors no matter how simple the command (I even tried `var=$(print "hello world")` and still a failure), and where it was placed in the awk script. Could this be due to having an awk script itself? I invoke the script with `awk -f testscript.script inputfile`

Comment: @KevinMoy Not `print`, use `echo`: `var=$(echo "hello world")`

Comment: What if a print statement is combined with an if statement? How would the command substitution change? i.e. storing `if(x > 5) {print "Hello World"}` into the `var` variable?